# How to download a byte array as a zip file in an AngularJS client?

Tags: angularjs, blob, angular-http, arraybuffer, filesaver.js

I'm sure this question and similar variants have been asked many times here over the years. I've gone through almost everything and am still unable to execute this properly.

I've a .NET Core API endpoint that returns a byte array that represents a zip file:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("download/{fileId}/")]
    public byte[] Download(long fileId)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I use AngularJS's `$http` service with `arraybuffer` as the `responseType` to initiate a request:

```
    // AngularJS service (fileApiService)

    this.downloadFile = function (fileId) {
        var url = apiUrl + 'download/' + fileId;
        return $http.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    };
```

I get a valid response and it's handled like below. I use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to access the `saveAs` method and the `Blob` constructor:

```
    // AngularJS controller

    fileApiService.downloadFile(fileId)
        .then(function (response) {
           var data = response.data;
           var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

           FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'file.zip');   
        })
        .catch(function () {
            ...
        });
```

[image: response]

Unfortunately this results in a corrupted archive file regardless of whatever tweak I do to the above code. The Window 10 zip utility complains that the archive cannot be opened even if the file is not empty. I've tried the following:

- Setting `responseType` as `blob` in the `$http.get()` request and directly passing that into `FileSaver.saveAs()` method
- Passing `application/zip` and other MIME types to the `Blob` constructor
- Passing `{ autoBOM: true }` to the `FileSaver.saveAs()` method

I'm suspecting that this is an encoding issue as another ASP.NET Web Forms application can download a valid zip file from the same API endpoint.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
fileApiService.downloadFile(fileId)
.then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;

    function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        sliceSize = sliceSize || 512; // sliceSize represent the bytes to be process in each batch(loop), 512 bytes seems to be the ideal slice size for the performance wise 

        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        var byteArrays = [];

        for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
        return blob;
    }

    var blob = b64toBlob(data, 'application/octet-stream');

    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'file.zip');
})
.catch(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried a solution using atob() earlier and yours now. I get this: "Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded"

Comment: I can also see that there are some '=' characters at the end of the response. I'm guessing it means there's some padding in the base64 content and the string is intact

Comment: Erm, just noticed your response.data is the byte array. Can you try just change the code from new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }); to new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

Comment: That didn't work either. It still downloads an invalid archive!

Comment: I tried your original solution after removing responseType: 'arraybuffer' from the $http.get() request and it worked! What do you think is the reason?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I think it's depends on what type that you returned from web API. For your case, it is byte array/array buffer, the reason it worked after you removed the response type because the function b64toBlob is accepting the data in string format instead of byte array/array buffer.

Comment: Yes, but I'm unsure why it didn't work with arraybuffer as it always does